# Regex using re2

Tags: regex, kusto-explorer

I am using re2 (https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). I have a string of the form:

```
"String \\r\\n more text \\ \\ \" abc "
```

In this string I want to remove all backslash except one with quotes i.e. `\"`. Is there some way I can write a regex for it. I want my final string t look like

```
"String rn more text   \" abc "
```

I tried writing the regex using: `\\*([^\"])`

I am using Kusto's replace regex function (which in-turn uses re2).

Comment: I think this needs negative lookahead, but RE2 doesn't appear to have this.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes RE2 does not have it. Is there an alternate way

Comment: Your last question related to this said you were using Python. Why don't you use its standard `re` library?

Comment: @Barmar: That was for a different project. In this project I need to use Kusto: which has dependence on re2

Comment: If the "string of the form" is actually a *string literal*, then you have `\r\n` text and the `\"` is just a mere `"` (with no literal backslash in front). Thus, all you need is something like `extend replaced=replace_string(str, '\\', '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp will work except if the quote is at the end of the string, because `[^"]` won't match there. So use an alternative to match the end there.

```
\\*([^\"]|$)
```

Comment: I tried it with Kusto. The able regex is not able to replace \\r\\n. Am I missing something

Comment: I don't know Kusto. I don't know why that doesn't work with `\r\n`, since that should be matched by `[^"]`. But you could try using the `m` flag in the regexp, which makes `$` match line endings.

Comment: Sorry I dont know much about m flag. Can you please help with how to set it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Kusto, I don't know how you specify flags. In Python it would be the `flags=re.M` argument to any of the `re.XXX` functions.

Comment: If there's no similar argument, you can put `(?m)` at the beginning of the regexp.